# I want to type conversion in Quartus2 Verilog

Tags: verilog, quartus

I want to type conversion in Quartus2 Verilog.......

integer to reg

ex)

integer a = 10;

reg[3:0] b;

$cast(b,a);

but $cast is not supported synthesis..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly cast between integral types; Verilog is loosely typed and defines implicit casts between many different types. You can just write:

```
b = a;
```

Explicit casts is a SystemVerilog feature having two different forms: static and dynamic.

You use a static cast to a built-in or used defined type:

```
typedef reg [3:0] uint4_t;

b = uint4_t'(a);
```

And that would be acceptable for synthesis.

The dynamic `$cast` operator is targeted for class variable assignments with inheritance. It would not expect synthesis tools to support this.

Comment: In my quartus,  tpyedef is not available.....   Is there any other way?

Comment: You can just write `b= a;` there is no need for a cast. In any case `typedfef` should be available if you turn on SystemVerilog.

Comment: thank you very much. but typedef really does not work. so solved it b=a